# How to carry *one* SD card in a crowded knapsack without losing it?

Tags: organization

My son will be required to carry a micro SD card back and forth to ninth grade next year.  What can we put it in so it doesn't get lost or damaged?  (Extra challenge: He has ADHD.)

For a flash drive, we bought one with a little hole on one end.  We put a simple, sturdy key ring through the hole, and attached it to a lanyard.  That worked well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If he carries a smart phone or tablet, that makes a fine place to install the Micro SD when it's not being used to transfer data to or from the school.  He's a good bit less likely to lose such a device than something smaller than a postage stamp, and he can actually *use* (some of) the information on the Micro SD while he's carrying it (say, on a school bus).

Comment: Each student in our district is given a Chromebook.  Would that work?

Comment: If it has a MicroSD reader slot, it'd be a perfect home.  Even if it has a full size SD slot, adapters are easy to come by.

Answer (score 3):

Use a case which is big enough not to get lost.

You can get small cases which are pretty much waterproof and you can often put a keyring through the case, so you can attach it to the lanyard.

I googled SD card case, and found a lot of pictures, (but all on commercial sites.)

Answer (score 2):

Not a lifehack as such, but they do sell cases for sd cards which attach to your key ring or lanyards. This will both protect the sd card, and if keys are attached make it easier to keep track of.

*Edit:* We're not supposed to advertise specific cases, but here is a Google search returning multiple cases: [micro sd keychain case](https://www.google.no/search?q=micro%20sd%20keychain%20case&tbm=isch)

Comment: That's what I need.  Can you post an image or a link to one such product?  // I don't know the definition of a lifehack, but I would say that I'm looking for a product or repurposed object that will help us cope with a neurological difference.

Comment: This is what I wrote in an answer 9 hours before you.

Answer (score 1):

A case for the sd card could solve the problem (as Willeke suggested), but would require keeping track of it while using the sd card and putting the card back in each time.

Keeping it permanently plugged into the computer could work (as Zeiss Ikon suggested), but would require the laptop to have the proper port, and may fall out.

Now for my solution, use a device like this (not necessary the same brand):
[image]

A small rubber band tightly wrapped around could help hold the card.

It is not very clear from the image, but it has a loop in the end to which a string can be attached. The device is called a "USB 2.0 SD/MMC Memory Card Reader", and the web page I found it on is http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-2-0-sd-mmc-memory-card-reader-black/3602009.p?skuId=3602009

Comment: Thanks.  Question: how do we prevent loss of this nice gadget (by the way what's it called?)?

Comment: It is not very clear from the image, but it has a loop in the end to which a string can be attached. The device is called a "USB 2.0 SD/MMC Memory Card Reader", and the web page I found it on is http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-2-0-sd-mmc-memory-card-reader-black/3602009.p?skuId=3602009.

Comment: This looks encouraging -- I like the hole and the string/ribbon.  But the rubber band makes me nervous.  I have broken a lot of rubber bands.

Comment: The rubber band can be replaced by a piece of tape, provided it does not damage the by impeding heat dissipation. Note that this may not be needed if there is sufficient friction to hold the card.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any contact lens case you can use that or I used to carry my sd card into an empty vapor-rub case as shown below.
[image: vaporub]

Comment: Very nice.  Now if I could find something like this that could somehow attach to a lanyard....

Comment: Whatever you do, don't put your contact lenses in a vapo-rub case, no matter how much you clean it.

Comment: @JohnCanon read it carefully

Comment: I hear you. I was being comical